# how to parent tag with nested tag

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have an XML File that looks like this:

```
<SNS>
<SN>aaaa</SN>
<SN>bbbb</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
<SN>dddd</SN>
<SN>eeee</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
</SNS>
```

Required Output:

```
<SN>aaaa</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
<SN>bbbb</SN>
<LN>cccc</LN>
<SN>dddd</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
<SN>eeee</SN>
<LN>ffff</LN>
```

How to add every `<SN>` tag with `<LN>`?

Answer (score 2):

Just process all `SN` elements and in their template copy the following sibling `LN`:

```
  <xsl:template match="SNS">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SN"/>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="SN">
      <xsl:copy-of select="., following-sibling::LN[1]"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifq2

In XSLT 3 you could also simply process each `SN` and its sibling `LN` and push them through the identity transformation:

```
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="SNS">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="SN!(., following-sibling::LN[1])"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifq2/1